# Blender for SPH Simulation of Multiphase Flow

Tags: fluid-simulation

Hi I'm a Blender newb and I've been looking to do some fluid simulations of a multi-phase flow, I was wondering if this is something that can be done in Blender?

Basically I want to do a Smooth Particle Hydrodynamics simulation of a sphere falling and splashing on the free surface of a liquid body with specified viscosity and surface tension, but I also want (if possible) to include the surrounding air into the picture. So the idea is to dip the sphere in the liquid very fast so that it splashes and liquid goes up and around the sphere to form a ''splash crown''.

Comment: Please show your work, if possible, as a Blender screen capture.  Of course Blender offers fluid simulation .. and so do other addons.  If you have a visual reference that can be included in your question that may help.  Some BUs have very specific needs and other BUs have wide latitude.  Consider forces and all the other features of your fluid simulation.

Comment: Liquid cannot currently influence rigid bodies, if that’s what you mean. Such scenarios have to be faked.

Comment: It's the other way around, so the rigid body hits the liquid and makes it splash and go up around the solid.